# Assigning unique value to buttons on a table [JS/jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a table with multiple buttons. I want to assign a numerical ID to each of these. When the button is pressed, it will do a ajax call.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
<tr><td><button id="btn-0"></tr></td> <!-- generated via DOM !-->
<tr><td><button id="btn-1"></tr></td>
...
<tr><td><button id="btn-n"></tr></td>

<script>
...
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                $("#btn-" + i).click(doAjax(i));
        }
...
</script>
```

I feel like there is a *much* better way to do this that I have not thought of. What is a good way to represent an array of buttons that is both HTML and JS friendly?

Comment: BTW, your button elements arent closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise you to but them in a class, and then give them their ids like this:

```
<button class="button" id="1"></button>
```

You can then use this javascript:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    doAjax(this.id);
});
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest method. So would I have to create a empty CSS class for this? I tried basically what you have above with an empty 'button' class and it didn't work. onClick=alert(0) works fine though?

Comment: This is really how you should do it, What do you mean empty class?
you can fill the button with text if you need.

Comment: Hmm strange it works when I try it on a separate test HTML file. Would you possibly know how I could debug this? Google Dev Tools is showing no errors, but nothing is happening on my main code!

Comment: What type of errors? And what do you mean seperate HTML

Comment: AHA! I have to do setup the jQuery click event AFTER I do the table generation. Thank you very much for your help, you have alleviated a headache.

Comment: Glad to help; remember, always try to limit the repetition of code!

Answer (score 0):

It would better to reference them by class, if you're permitted to alter the code that generates the tags to begin with.

```
<button id="btn-0" class="my-class">

$(".my-class").click(function(){
    doAjax(this.id); // the elements id that was  clicked
});
```

Of course, you can always pass the entire object (`this`) if it contains additional information useful in your doAjax() method.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop and assigning `id` to each `<button>` element is not necessary. You can delegate `click` event at `<button>` elements to parent `"table"` or `"body"` selector.

Use `.index()` to pass the `index` of element within collection of elements to `doAjax()` function.

```js
$(function() {
  var table = "<table><tbody>" 
              + "<tr><td><button>click</button></td></tr>" 
              + "<tr><td><button>click</button></td></tr>" 
              + "<tr><td><button>click</button></td></tr>" 
              + "</tbody></table>";
  var selector = "table button";
  $("body").append(table)
    .on("click", selector, function() {
      var index = $(this).index(selector);
      console.log(index);
      // do ajax stuff
      // doAjax(index);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, add a general class to your buttons and add the attribute **data** with name **id** like this:

HTML:

```
<button class="button-action" data-id="1">
<button class="button-action" data-id="2">
<button class="button-action" data-id="3">
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-action', fuction() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); // here you get the id of the attribute data from the current clicked button

    // Here you handle the request ajax

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // Here you put the type of request POST / GET
        url: 'http://my-url.com', // Here you need to put your url
        data: {
             id: id, // Here is the id of the current button

             // Here you can add other variables to sent it in the request
        },
        success: function(response) {
             // Here you handle the response
        }
    });
});
```

Tell me if this was helpful, regards!